# Angular 2 lever checkbox input

Tags: angular

I would like to implement a lever checkbox which is used to show/hide columns of the table. Showing and hiding works fine and lever is shown correctly initially (ON position), and when I click the first time it is switched correctly to OFF position, but after that, every subsequent click leaves it at off position

```
<a class="dropdown-item" >
    <div class="switch">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" (click)="HideId = !HideId" [checked]="!HideId">
            <span class="lever"></span>
            ID
        </label>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: please consider creating a runnable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Use camelCase variable names.

Check out this Plunker I made. This will toggle visibility of the `<span class="lever"></span>` element.
https://plnkr.co/edit/wt2JyzphmzcCdipYA9Me?p=preview

Comment: I am using PascalCase because I am coding with C# also, it is a pain thinking about it every time. By making variable change through component everything worked as charm

Comment: Awesome! Good luck and have fun in the beautiful world of Angular :)